# How can i get the column name to the left of a column with a known name?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

If i have an excel sheet that i read into pandas, how can i get the name of the column that is to the left side of another column that we know the name of?
Reason for the question is that the excel sheets we get contains both named and unnamed columns.

The ones without column names are then automatically named "Unnamed: x" (where x is a number).

Because I have a column with a known name and i also know that it is the column to the left of it that contains the values i need, I would like to use the named column as a reference to get the name of the unknownly named column.

Example: These are the columns if i print them in python:

```
in: df.columns

out: Index(['Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3',
       'Col4', 'Col5', 'Col6', 'Col7',
       'Col8', 'Col9', 'Col10',
       'Col11', 'Col12', 'Col13',
       'Col14', 'Col15', 'Unnamed: 15', 'Unnamed: 16',
       'Unnamed: 17', 'Col19', 'Col20', 'Unnamed: 20',
       'Col22', 'Col23',
       'Col24', 'Col25', 'Col26', 'Col27', 'Unnamed: 27',
       'Unnamed: 28', 'Filename', 'Unnamed: 30', 'Unnamed: 31',
       'Unnamed: 32', 'Unnamed: 33', 'Unnamed: 34', 'Unnamed: 35',
       'Unnamed: 36', 'Unnamed: 37', 'Unnamed: 38', 'Unnamed: 39',
       'Unnamed: 40', 'Unnamed: 41', 'Unnamed: 42', 'Unnamed: 43',
       'Unnamed: 44', 'Unnamed: 45'],
      dtype='object')
```

As can be seen here, there is a column named "Filename" and to the left of it there is a column auto named "Unnamed: 28". Because it can change name baed on the amount of unnamed columns before it, i need to use "Filename" column as a reference to get the column name "Unnamed: 28" so that i later on can get the values from that column for other purposes.

Any suggestions?

Edit:

I found another solution to the problem.
Using get_indexer i can get the index of that column and use it to get the data in the column.

```
df.iloc[:, df.columns.get_indexer(['Filename'])-1]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could find the index of the column whose name you know, decrement by one and then find the name of the column you don't know:

```
column_number = [i-1 for i, x in enumerate(df.columns) if x=='Filename']
df.columns[column_number[0]]
```

With your columns this gives 'Unnamed 28'

That said, I think it might pay off to work on properly importing the data, rather than writing corrections afterwards.

Comment: Thanks. Will give it a try.
The problem is that we get the excel sheets from another company, and it is really hard and time consuming to get stuff like this to change in their system. So this is a workaround from my side to know that we can handle the files as they come now, hopefully the changes in their system will later on be implemented so that we get identical files each time and hopefully with all columns named.